# If $A$ is a matrix of size $n\times n$, and $A^2+A+2I=0$

Tags: matrices

If $A$ is a matrix of size $n\times n$, and $A^2+A+2I=0$, check whether $A$ is singular or not and find its inverse if it exists.

I can find the inverse by simply multiplying the given equation with $A^{-1}$.

$$A+I+2A^{-1}=0$$

$$A^{-1}=-\frac{1}{2}(A+I)$$

But how can I check if its singular or not?

Comment: Did you try to use the determinant function?

Comment: @Abbraxas Whats that?

Comment: Another JEE prep question?

Comment: The exam is tomorrow @N.S.JOHN My future will be decided tomorrow.

Comment: Good luck. I will be seeing you at IIT MUMBAI

Comment: @N.S.JOHN hopefully. I am just an average student. I have BITS and NIT with me.

Comment: Rewrite as $\left(-\frac{1}{2}A-\frac{1}{2}I\right)A=I$. That shows $A$ is invertible (non-singular) by exhibiting the inverse.

Comment: An invertible matrix is non-singular, there's no point to calculate the determinant.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the nonzero determinant should be viewed as a consequence, instead of the definition of invertibility/nonsingularity. Based on my experience, there are many people in this forum confused this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $A(A+I)=-2I$ and take the determinant on both sides. This gives $$\det(A)\det(A+I)=(-2)^n\neq 0,$$ hence $\det(A)\neq 0$.

Comment: There is a typo: $n$ should be at exponent.

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is singular, then there exists a vector $v\neq 0$ such that $Av=0$. In that case
$$
0=0v=(A^2+A+2I)v=A(Av)+Av+2v=2v,
$$
a contradiction.